# Why doesn't os.system('cls') clear the recent output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, os.system

I am always using `system('cls')` in C language before using Dev-C++. Now I am studying Python and using Pycharm 2020.2.3.

I tried to use `os.system('cls')`. Here is my program:

```
import os

print("clear screen")
n = int(input(""))
if n == 1:
    os.system('cls')
```

There is no error in my program but it is not clearing the recent output.

This is the output of my program:

[image: screenshot of my output]

What seems to be the problem why it is not clearing the recent output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PhCharm displays the output of your running module using the output console. In order for your terminal commands under `os.system()` to work, you need to emulate your terminal inside the output console.

1. Select 'Edit Configurations' from the 'Run' menu.
2. Under the 'Execution' section, select 'Emulate terminal in output console'

[JetBrains Sergey Karpov Adds](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403798395538-Seeking-better-answer-about-terminal-emulation?page=1#community_comment_4403821884690):

> Our Run window doesn't support some of the things that one can do in
> the terminal. One of them is clearing the output.
>
> When trying to clear
> the output in a 'non-terminal' output window, PyCharm even shows that
> the **TERM environment variable is not set**.
>
> Setting that variable
> manually may help in some cases, but other terminal-specific things
> are still missing, which is why we have an option to emulate the
> terminal in the Run window.

Comment: Wow. That was not obvious. Thanks for solving a 2 day mystery!!!

Answer (score 4):

This code works perfectly well. I think there is a problem how you are running it. you should run it with commmand prompt.

if still not working.

```
os.system('cls')  # on windows
os.system('clear')  # on linux / Mac
```

You can test your code here
https://www.python.org/shell/

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
import time
import os

while True:
    os.system('cls')
    age = int(input('how old are you?'))
    if age >= 18:
        print('you are at the legal age in America to vote!')
    else:
        print('you cannot vote!')
    time.sleep(3)
```